# Managing Fragments on Android Foldable

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am creating a new Android Project and soon android foldable devices will be launched. I have an Activity which has fragment called first fragment.
First Fragment has a button called first button which open second fragment which has a button called second and on click of second, third fragment opens.

Suppose user is in third fragment and user decides to unfold his device, will the user go back to fragment one or will he stay in fragment three. As far as I have understood from the Developer Summit, the activity will be destroyed and recreated when user unfolds his device so technically user goes backs to first fragment leading to poor user experience.

So my question is should I consider even using fragments?, If yes how to manage state so that user goes to the same fragment he was when he folds or unfolds his device.

Following is my code if I am changing fragments

```
private fun displayView(fragment: Fragment?, title: String) {
        if (fragment != null) {
            supportFragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.framelayout_activity_main, fragment, title).commit()
        }
    }
```

Comment: "so technically user goes backs to first fragment leading to poor user experience" -- that is not the default behavior of fragments. When an activity is destroyed and recreated, the same mix of fragments in the same states is also recreated. If that is not happening for you, there is a bug in your code.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am on fragment three and when I rotate the device, which recreates the activity, I am moved to fragment one. What could be possible cause of bug, any idea?

Comment: Presumably, you are committing a `FragmentTransaction` that is causing this change, perhaps in `onCreate()` of the activity. You might consider editing this question and providing a [mcve] demonstrating how you are setting up the fragments.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have edited the question, please have a look

Comment: I recommend that you look at `onCreate()` of your activity and see if you are always executing a `FragmentTransaction` there to set up the first fragment. If so, do not do that on a configuration change (e.g., only set up the first fragment if the `Bundle` passed into `onCreate()` is not `null`).

Comment: @CommonsWare You are right. For setting my first fragment I am calling the above code in onCreate of Activity. How to set it then so the fragment is visible when user opens the app, if not in onCreate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `onCreate()`, you only want to execute a `FragmentTransaction` if this activity is being
newly created, instead of being recreated from a configuration change. Or, more accurately,
you only want to execute a `FragmentTransaction` if you do not already have fragments in the state that you want them.

So, a typical approach is to see if you already have a fragment in your container:

```
override fun onCreate(state: Bundle) {
  super.onCreate(state)

  if (supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.framelayout_activity_main) == null) {
    // do something to show your fragment
  }

  // other good stuff goes here
}
```

On the first `onCreate()` invocation, `findFragmentById()` will return `null`, so you execute your code to display your first fragment. On a subsequent `onCreate()` invocation after a configuration change, Android will have already set up your fragment(s) for you by the time `onCreate()` is called. So, in that case, `findFragmentById()` will return something other than `null`, so you know that you already have a fragment in your container and do not need to do anything more.